# Laravel - Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a custom fuction on my Model to check if a user belongs to a external api list.

```
public function mailchimp()
    {
        $mailchimp = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/']);

        try
        {
            $checkEmail = $mailchimp->request('GET', 'lists/768ce70724/members/' . md5($this->email), [
                'headers' => [ 'Authorization' => 'apikey ' . config('globals.mailchimp_key') ]
            ]);
        }

        catch( \Exception $exception ) {
            //if ( $exception->getResponse()->getStatusCode() === 404) { return 'not a subscriber'; }

            return 'error'; // where the error occurs
        }

        $result = json_decode( $checkEmail->getBody() );

        //return    $result->status;
        return 'success';
    }
```

This is how I call the method:

```
$emails = $newsletter
                ->with('user')
                ->with('mailchimp')
                ->paginate(config('globals.results_per_page'));

return $emails;
```

Error: http://prntscr.com/dbm2ts

Answer (score 0):

When you're usng `with()` Laravel is trying to [load a relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). So, `mailchimp()` should be a relation here.

Comment: But I don't need a relationship, I just want to perform code for each record and get that on the returned results, how can I do that?

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira why don't you just build separate array or collection and concatinate it with `$emails` collection? Or maybe just use it separately.

Comment: I'm retrieving the emails from database, I need to do this at the same time the emails are being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to go to the method on the controller but I managed to access it from the view which works well!